# How to validate an input string allowing only integers that are 9, 10, 12, or 13 digits long?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I validate an input string so it only allows integers 9, 10, 12, or 13 digits long?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You can test the `length` of the string and  test that the characters of the string are only digits. And [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a great playground.

Comment: What's the reason for specific lengths, are these a certain type of number, e.g. phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function meetsRequirements(str) {
    // make sure characters are only digits
    if (str.replace(/[0-9]/gi,"").length === 0) {
        // get number of digits
        numDigits = str.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, "").length;
        switch (numDigits) {
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should try it first and ask us specific question.
I am giving you sample example what you have wanted.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/633/

Use regular Expression for checking number and use `length` for checking length.

Try like this:
**jquery:**

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
var val = $('#no').val();
var  intLength = val.length;
if(intRegex.test(val) && (intLength == 9 || intLength == 10 || intLength == 12 )) {
   alert('I am a number and length '+intLength );
 }
 else {
      alert("wrong input!") ; 
 }
```

**Sample html:**

```
<input type="text" name="f1" value="" id="no">
<input type="button" value="submit!" id="f_submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't take into account leading or all zeros, if that is a concern, or negatives.

Comment: Or instead of comparing the length explicitly, you could just do `/^\d{9,13}$/`.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Kling  actually he wanted length (9,10,12)

Comment: Of course a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is not the only way to perform the test.

Comment: @AwladLiton, can simplify `if`: intRegex.test(val) && [9,10,12,13].indexOf(val.length)

Comment: @maximkou that does of course require ECMA5

Comment: Thanks. its all are same @maximkou

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like

```
function str_is_int(str) {
    return str === ((+str) | 0).toString();
}
```

Then

```
if (str_is_int(my_string) && my_string.length >= 9 && my_string.length <= 13) {
    // pass
} else {
    // fail
}
```